# Migrating 32-bit ARM code to a 64-bit development environment

Tags: c, linux, arm

I have a GTK-based ARM project that was historically developed on a 32-bit Ubuntu virtual machine. Presently, I'm attempting to migrate that to a new 64-bit Arch Linux development box. I'm not sure what to do with the errors produced by the two routes I've taken.

If I tell the linker to use /usr/lib the compilation will halt telling me

```
/usr/lib/librt.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

So, assuming that was a 32-vs-64-bit issue, I directed the gcc toward /usr/lib32 and received the following

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib32/librt.so when searching for -lrt
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib32/librt.a when searching for -lrt
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib32/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib32/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi - ld: cannot find -lssl
```

and so on. I tried installing lib32-sqlite from the Arch repository to no avail.

With either directory, I receive the following warnings many, many times over, which I'm also unsure of

```
/usr/include/pthread.h:672:6: warning: '__regparm__' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
/usr/include/pthread.h:684:3: warning: '__regparm__' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
/usr/include/pthread.h:729:6: warning: '__regparm__' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
```

I'm not sure if that's simply an artifact from outdated code being compiled against up-to-date libraries or what, but it's something I'll want to resolve before too long.

EDIT: My target architecture is an ARM926EJ-S / i.MX27

Comment: It might help to indicate which 64-bit ARM architecture. From what I've seen, it's extremely new

Comment: It looks like you may be attempting to link libs from an incorrect architecture (e.g. i586) with your ARM executable.  That won't work. Try `file /usr/lib32/librt.so` to find out which architecture it is.

Comment: Oh, of course. I added the architecture. Not very new. Also, I'm going to look into the "file" output for the old development box and compare it with the new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess and say that your crosscompiling environment is not referencing the right libraries/header files. That is, they are referencing the build libraries/headers (i586?) and not the croscompiling libraries/headers for ARM `arm-linux-gnueabi`.

Comment: Yup. More research illustrated for me just how incomplete my attempts at compiling this code was. I've never touched an ARM board before, so I hadn't even downloaded the BSP from the manufacturer, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile a 64 bits program and then linked with lib32 library.

You have 2 solutions:

- Generate a 32 bits program linked against lib32
- Generate a fully 64 bits program linked against 64 bits lib